# How to make connection between 2 dataframes based on the sentence length and mask it based on ID to the other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 csv files which contains sentences inside them  and trying to make a program that checks the sentences length based on the words and if the sentence has more than 3  words add it to another csv and take the same ID from the second csv to a new csv as well, as far as I know I need to use mask for the second part but it does not work for me this is what I'm trying

my code is returning true and false instead of the sentences with the length of 3 words or more

```
fdata = pd.read_csv(firstinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)

firstdata= fdata['sentences'].str.split().str.len().gt(3)

sdata = pd.read_csv(secondtinput, names=['sentences'], skiprows=skip)
seconddata=sdata[sdata.index.isin(firstdata.index)]

firstdata.to_csv("new_data.csv", index=False, header=False)
seconddata.to_csv("new_data2.csv", index=False, header=False)



----------------------
#first dataframe example 
----------------------
#bye
#how are you 
#I want to die
#I was home
#I went to sleep at work
#he have a bad reputation
#it was me who went to him 
#have  good sleep home
#hi you
#hi

----------------------
#second  dataframe example 
----------------------
#bye
#halaw kuy bashii
#damawe bmrm 
#la malawa bum
#la  
#aw kabraya bash nya 
#awa mn bum chum bo lay
#xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa 
# halaw you
#hi


----------------------
#first dataframe output 
----------------------

#how are you 
#I want to die
#I was home
#I went to sleep at work
#he have a bad reputation
#it was me who went to him 
#have  good sleep home

----------------------
#second  dataframe output 
----------------------

#halaw kuy bashii
#damawe bmrm 
#la malawa bum
#la 
#aw kabraya bash nya 
#awa mn bum chum bo lay
#xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa
```

Comment: and what's the expected output?

Comment: 2 csv files first one contains any sentences with 3 or more words from first dataframe, and second takes the same ID of first dataframe and pass that sentence. let me add the expected output as well

Comment: check the output please I added an example

Comment: see my answer (finished editing just now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with this line of code I think:

```
firstdata= fdata['sentences'].str.split().str.len().gt(3)
```

Try this instead:

```
firstdata = fdata.loc[df1['sentences'].str.split().str.len().gt(2)]
```

`firstdata` output:

```
    sentences
1   how are you
2   I want to die
3   I was home
4   I went to sleep at work
5   he have a bad reputation
6   it was me who went to him
7   have good sleep home
```

`seconddata` output:

```
    sentences
1   halaw kuy bashii
2   damawe bmrm
3   la malawa bum
4   la esh nustm
5   aw kabraya bash nya
6   awa mn bum chum bo lay
7   xaweki xosh basar bba la malawa
```

Comment: one more question if you can help with this code fdata.loc[df1['sentences'].str.split().str.len().gt(3)] returns anything with 3 words or more what is I want to put a range like  from  3 words  till 5 words is that doable ?

Comment: `firstdata = fdata.loc[(df1['sentences'].str.split().str.len().gt(2)) & (df1['sentences'].str.split().str.len().lt(6))]`. There is also a `.between()` function.